# Angular D3 bar chart animation

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/MErMvIgG9MOdXmjBPZVq?p=preview

I have a simple D3 bar chart in Angular.

I want the bars height animate from the bottom upwards.

In my example they are animating from the top downwards.

I'm sure this a simple fix but I'm stuck.

```
    private drawBars() {
        this.g.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(this.data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", (d) => this.x(d.letter) )
            .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .delay((d, i) => {
                return i * 50;
            })
            .attr("y", (d) => this.y(d.frequency) )
            .attr("height", (d) => this.height - this.y(d.frequency) )
            .attr('fill', (d, i)=>{
              return this.colors[i]
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `y` attribute specified *before* the transition. Because of that, `y` assumes the default value of `0`, which is the top of the SVG.

Thus, you just need to set the `y` attribute before calling `transition()`:

```
.attr("y", this.height )
```

Here is the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xXBwGpu0zHIjj9GAzanb?p=preview